# Detecting the position of a div and firing a function

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

im trying to fire a function when a div reaches a certain level in the scroll.

Could someone help me out with this?

Code / fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6hJeT/5/

Comment: And the problem is? Stack Overflow is not rentacoder, y'know..

Comment: That's right, at Stack Overflow coders work for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6hJeT/20/

looks like about the same answer as Nicola

Comment: Thanks for this! Although im having a few issues implementing it... Basically it is firing the event straight away as soon as scroll is touched

Comment: It works great in the fiddle example, however when i try to use it for some reason bottom-div have a top position value of 0

Comment: @jimmy huh... do you have a test site up that I could take a look at?

Comment: sure... http://bit.ly/qT8ToI if i manually set middle-wrap position:absolute, top:600. it works. but i dont know the position as top-wrap is browserheight.

Comment: ive fixed this by using the height of top-wrap instead of the position of middle-wrap.. However is there a way to remove the background-colour of a div in that function?

Comment: remove background color?  I believe you can with .css("background-color","transparent")

Comment: sorry again... background: none sorted it! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var shape = $('#shape').position();
    var bottomDiv = $('#bottom-div').position();
    if (shape.top > bottomDiv.top){
        alert('passed');  
    }

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/6hJeT/11/

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't realize that on objects with `position: fixed` the position value actually changes as the window scrolls down.

Answer (score 1):

Using `window.scrollTop()` will get you [there](http://jsfiddle.net/6hJeT/15/).

Alterntively, for more complicated cases you may want to look at [jquery waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
if($('#shape').offset().top >= $('#top-div').height()) alert("Boo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/6hJeT/21/

The trick is checking the `scrollTop` of the body (which means how much user has scrolled down) and compare it to the top position of your bottom div.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ((document.body.scrollTop +  + $("#shape").height()) >= $("#bottom-div").position().top)
        alert("Boo");
});
```